# Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use exception - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to link a 2d list of objects to a contentcontrol.  I'm getting an exception that I don't understand.  Could someone clarify it for me?  (I tried setting the first.ItemsSource property in C# as well to a NationMetrics object that I declared in code - it gave me the same exception)

Outer Exception:

Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.

Inner Exception:

Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

The NationMetrics class:

```
public class NationMetrics
{
     List<List<Field>> _Nations = new List<List<Field>>();

     public List<List<Field>> Nations { get { return _Nations; } set { _Nations = value; } }

}
```

Here's the snippet from my MainWindow.xaml where the exception is being triggered

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="first" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level1}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nations, Source={StaticResource nationMetric}}" />
</Grid>
```

Here's the snippet from my Window.Resources which defines nationMetric

```
<local:NationMetrics x:Name="nm" x:Key="nationMetric" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try out something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="inner">
                    <TextBlock Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="outer">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource inner}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ItemsControl x:Name="itemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nations, Source={StaticResource nationMetric}}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource outer}">
```

This basically identifies that there is a list within in a list and does the binding appropriately. I haven't tried it, but I think this is the approach!

Other resources:

[WPF: How to create a custom items control panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538881/wpf-how-to-create-a-custom-items-control-panel)

[Binding 2 dimensional Collection to some control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397153/binding-2-dimensional-collection-to-some-control)

Comment: Hmm...the original xaml template that I had was

`<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level1">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DataTemplate_Level2}">
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Level2">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>`

Yours worked - does the inner have to be declared before the outer?

Comment: XAML, HTML, CSS etc are all Imperative/Declarative languages. This means that code is read from top to bottom and that variables changed don't affect other dependent variables. So yes, this would mean that the order of declaring resources plays a part in the final result. For more on declarative programming languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming. I'm glad it worked! :)